# Image processing storage of image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-science

I am unable to understand the following question, could any one explain me what exactly is it asking?

> Suppose that an image of dimension **5*6** inches has detail to the
>   frequency of **600** dots per inch in each direction. How many samples are
>   required to preserve the information in the image? if the dynamic
>   range of the pixel values is between **0** and **200**, how many megabytes do
>   we need to store the whole image without compression?

I tried to solve this way, but just first part I did I do not know this is correct or not:

```
  5*6*600 = 18000
```

I think **18000** are total no of pixels required to preserve the information of image 
but do not know this is correct or not but how to find megabytes for storage?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's **600** dpi in both the horizontal and the vertical.

Next you have to consider the bit depth.  Looks like **200** values - I'm going to assume that's per channel.  So 3 bytes per pixel.

`( 5 * 600 ) * ( 6 * 600 ) = 10,800,000` **pixels**

`10,800,000 * 3 = 32,400,000` **bytes**

`32,400,000 / 1024 = 31,640.625` **kilobytes**

`31,640.625 / 1024 = 30.899047852` **megabytes**

Comment: Why 3 bytes per pixel, this should be bits/pixels and why 3 reason ??

Comment: A byte has a range from 0 to 255.  So you will need one byte to store one value.  There are 3 channels minimum per pixel - more if you are using transparency.

Comment: @Dan-o Only one channel needed for grayscale. I would have expected the problem statement to specify the number of channels if it was significant. (Looks like a textbook problem to me.)

Comment: @beaker: true.  its pretty rare to be working with grayscale images though.  They are kind of specialized.  The *vast majority* of images are RGB, with a significant portion of those being ARGB.  This answer also doesn't cover things like indexed bitmaps (which may or may not be more space-efficient depending on the particular image).  So there are many factors to consider.  As this *does* appear to be homework I went with the most common scenario and left the rest up to the student.